# jquery traversing and tables

Tags: jquery, traversal

This problem is making me a bit crazy.

I have something like this

```
  <h3>Feeds
   <span><a class="smallbutton create_feed" href="javascript:;">
    <strong>Create New</strong>
    </a>
   </span>
   <span class="div_form_add_feed">
    <a class="smallbutton btn_save_feeds" href="javascript:;">
    <strong> Add </strong></a>
   </span>
   </h3>
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=1 class="table">
<tr><td>
<div class="get_feeds_news">test</div></td></tr></table>
```

I want the Add link class "smallbutton btn_save_feeds" to replace the div "get_feeds_news" with something else. But I cannot seem to traverse to it using $(this) in jQuery.

What is the right way to traverse from the Add link class "smallbutton btn_save_feeds"  to change someting in the div "get_feed_news"? I tried the following but didnt work.

```
$(this).closest('.get_feeds_news').html('hihi');
```

Is the problem because it's inside a table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Scott - I added another solution to my answer, though if there will be a definite number of these elements, giving the element an ID would be better than traversal. If that's not the case, see my updated traversal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`closest()` will not work since the element you're searching for is not an ancestor of the button.

If `get_feeds_news` is the only occurrence of that class, you could simply use `$('.get_feeds_news')`

Otherwise, you could do something like:

`$(this).closest('h3').next().find('.get_feeds_news')`

jQuery has many ways to traverse. This is certainly not the only way to go about it. If your layout changes, there will be some way to accomplish what you need.

Comment: ah.. that's the thing. i have 2 instances of it.

Comment: I added a second example to grab the closest h3, then traverse to its next sibling, and find your get_feeds_news.

Answer (score 2):

you're missing the dot (plus a closing div tag)

```
$(this).closest('.get_feeds_news').html('hihi');
```

Comment: sorry about that. i wrote it wrong in the example. But in my code i had the dot and still didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

try fixing your html, you didn't close your get_feeds_news div:

```
<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=1 class="table">
<tr><td>
<div class="get_feeds_news"></div></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: sorry about that. i wrote it wrong in the example. But in my code i have it closed properly.

Answer (score 0):

you can select one of two elements by

```
$('.get_feed_news:eq(0)')
```

(or 1 for second)

or, if you have 2 links `smallbutton btn_save_feeds` (one for each `.get_feed_news`), you can use:

```
$('.get_feed_news').eq( $(this).index() )
```

what basically passes index to filter `.get_feed_news` with index of caller :]